# Math help for parallelograms on canvas

Tags: math, canvas, geometry

First let me say that I'm not very good with math. I have a canvas with multiple text "boxes" that are rotated to 300°, which basically makes them parallelograms. They are very similar to this:

[image]

I'm trying to detect if the mouse is over one of them, but I don't know how to do that. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Decomposition]

Each parallelogram can first of all be contained in a rectangular bounding box like the one illustrated above.  If the mouse is not within that rectangle, then it is definitely not a hit.  You have many easy tests for that already.  The rest of the space can be decomposed into the parallelogram of interest in green, and the areas you don't want.  So we just need to test if the mouse is in the red areas with the following tests:

Left: x < a - (a/h)*y

Right: x > (a+b) - (a/h)*y

If either of those conditions is true, then the mouse is outside the parallelogram.

- Note, in this case I am assuming y is 0 at the top and increases as you move down, and x is zero at the left and increases as you move right.

For more information about the value of a, we can turn to trig.

[image]

If we know the angle theta and h, then

a = h tan(Ɵ)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is to use the *inverse* transform on the mouse point and then do simple rectangle testing on the transformed point. As long as the affine transform you're using doesn't map everything to a line, it will have a well-defined inverse.